# The substitution u = sin(y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The substitution $u = \sin(y)$ converts any equation of the form
$\frac{dy}{dx} = Q(x)\sec(y) + R(x) \tan(y)$ to a linear equation. Prove this claim. I have know clue how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y$ is a solution to
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} = Q(x)\sec(y) + R(x)\tan(y).
\end{align}
Consider the function $u(x)= \sin [y(x)]$ and observe
\begin{align}
\frac{d u}{dx} =&\ \cos[y(x)] \frac{dy}{dx} = \cos y \left\{Q(x)\sec y+ R(x) \tan y \right\}\\
=&\ Q(x)+R(x)\sin y = Q(x)+R(x)u. 
\end{align}
Thus, $u=\sin[y(x)]$ solves a linear equation
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx} = Q(x) + R(x)u. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

1. Rewrite all the trig expressions in terms of $\sin(y)$ and $\cos(y)$.
2. Find $\frac{du}{dx}$ in terms of $\frac{dy}{dx}$
3. Make the substitutions.